# TextUtils how to implement?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm not sure how to implement TextUtils correctly in my code. I'm building a calculator but not sure how it should be implemented? It could be a small fix but no sure. Thanks in advance!

Heres my Code:

```
package com.mula.minicalculator;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.mula.minicalculator.R.id;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView scr;
Button buttonPlus;
Button buttonSub;
Button buttonX;
Button buttonDiv;

String oper = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scr = (TextView) findViewById(id.answerSum);

    // Elements
    buttonDiv = (Button) findViewById(id.buttonDiv);
    buttonX = (Button) findViewById(id.buttonX);
    buttonSub = (Button) findViewById(id.buttonSub);
    buttonPlus = (Button) findViewById(id.buttonPlus);



    // Set a Listener
    buttonDiv.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSub.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonX.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Now the numbers

    Button buttons[] = new Button[10];

    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(id.button0);
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(id.button1);
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(id.button2);
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(id.button3);
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(id.button4);
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(id.button5);
    buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(id.button6);
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(id.button7);
    buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(id.button8);
    buttons[9] = (Button) findViewById(id.button9);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    float buttons = 0;
    float result = 0;
```

// Problem Here

```
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(buttons.getText().toString()) {   
        return;
    }

    return;


    switch (view.getId()) {
        case id.buttonPlus:
            oper = "+";
            result = buttons + buttons;
            break;
        case  id.buttonSub:
            oper = "-";
            result = buttons - buttons;
            break;
        case id.buttonX:
            oper = "*";
            result = buttons * buttons;
            break;
        case id.buttonDiv:
            oper = "/";
            result = buttons / buttons;
            break;
        default:
            break;


    }

    scr.setText(buttons + " " + oper + " " + buttons + " = " + result);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is buttons? In the first code block, you are instantiating two versions of it, an array and a float. Your code is slightly confusing because you are using the same name (buttons) over and over, it is hard to understand what is supposed to be happening.

Comment: are you checking emptiness on the `TextView` scr or the `Button` buttons ? and why do you not just go `Whateverview.getText().toString().isEmpty()` or `Whateverview.getText().toString().length() == 0`

Comment: Hey @Elltz I'm checking the emptiness of Button buttons. I tried both "Whateverview.getText().toString().isEmpty() or Whateverview.getText().toString().length() == 0 " then says can not resolve symbol "getText" I just want all the buttons in the array to have functionality.

Comment: well if its button then  on your button object `if(button.getText().toString().length() == 0){ // its empty};`

Comment: you should let people know of your status on the question, Sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your empty check should be in this manner simultaneously for buttons in array

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(buttons[0].getText().toString()) 
{ 
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the emptiness of Button then

```
button.getText().toString().length() == 0 //all versions
```

also in your code check this

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(buttons.getText().toString()) {   
    return; // this takes you out of the method, if its empty
}

return; // this takes you out of the method,even if its not, 
//switch statements wont be called
```

so remove the second `return` i guess that's your problem